# How to I get a div that shows on hover, not to push content down on the page?

Tags: html, css

I have created the following

http://jsfiddle.net/fcW66/1/

CSS

```
.div_wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: 3333;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #cacaca;
    z-index: 1;
}
.div_two {
    display: none;
    height: 120px;
    background: #444;
    z-index: 999;
}
.div_one:hover .div_two {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_one">
        <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <div class="div_two">description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_one">
        <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <div class="div_two">description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_one">
        <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <div class="div_two">description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br style="clear:both;" />
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_one">
        <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <div class="div_two">description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_one">
        <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <div class="div_two">description</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="div_one">
        <img src="#" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
        <div class="div_two">description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When you hover over it shows the description, but it pushes the other divs further. I have tried giving the div_wrapper a fixed width, which fixes that problem but when the div2 appears it shows under the next div that is under it. I tried adding a z-index and it did not change anything. I need the div_two to show over the top of the divs that are below it and not change the layout.

Comment: `position: relative`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want white-space in the location of the object BEFORE hover, you would use `visibility`, not `display`.

`visibility:hidden`, instead of `display:none`

and `visibility:visible`, instead of `dislpay:block`

Comment: That's a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `position: absolute` to position this `div`.  Absolutely positioned elements do not take up space within their container preventing them from pushing other elements around.

In most cases such as this, you will want to set the parent element to `position: relative` as well, so that the absolute element can be positioned relative to its parent instead of the whole document.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcW66/7/

```
.div_one{
    position: relative;
}

.div_two {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: absolute;` to accomplish this.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QbAzY/

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute;` and `width: 100px;` to your `.div_two` rules

```
.div_two {
    display: none;
    height: 120px;
    background: #444;
    z-index: 999;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fcW66/6/)**

z-index only applies to positioned elements, so by setting position:absolute on your .div_two elements it not only allows the z-index to work, but it takes those elements out of the normal flow of the document and won't push the other divs down. Note that you also have two background rules on your .div_wrapper element, and a z-index rule that isn't doing anything.